# ¿Como combinar varios map, filter, reduce?

Tags: array, objeto, filtro, map, reduce

Tengo este objeto:

```
let data = {
            id: 0,
            estudio: [
                {
                    e_id: 1,
                    nombre: "estudio 1",
                    categoria: "producto",
                    active: true,
                },
                {
                    e_id: 2,
                    nombre: "estudio 2",
                    categoria: "producto 2",
                    active: false,
                },
            ],
            estudioConfig: [
                {
                    e_id: 1,
                    d_estudio: "prueba",
                    imagenes: [],
                },
                {
                    e_id: 2,
                    d_estudio: "prueba2",
                    imagenes: [],
                },
            ],
        }
```

Y quisiera seleccionar los **estudioConfig** que estén con el estado **true** y para conseguir esa información se tendría que comparar con el campo **estudio**, ya que comparten el mismo campo **e_id**, y toda esta operación realizarlo con funciones map, filter o reducer.

Resultado:

```
    [
     {
        e_id: 1,
        d_estudio: "prueba",
        imagenes: [],
     }
   ]
```

Gracias por sus respuestas.

Comment: ¿Y qué has intentado? Supongo que pretendes que alguien lo haga por ti. Te invito a leer [ask] y [mcve]. Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utiliza `reduce` para iterar sobre el array `data`. Cuando encuentres un elemento con la propiedad `active` en `true`, buscas su equivalente en  `estudioConfig` y lo agregas a tu array de salida.

Te adjunto una posible solución:

```js
let data = {
            id: 0,
            estudio: [
                {
                    e_id: 1,
                    nombre: "estudio 1",
                    categoria: "producto",
                    active: true,
                },
                {
                    e_id: 2,
                    nombre: "estudio 2",
                    categoria: "producto 2",
                    active: false,
                },
            ],
            estudioConfig: [
                {
                    e_id: 1,
                    d_estudio: "prueba",
                    imagenes: [],
                },
                {
                    e_id: 2,
                    d_estudio: "prueba2",
                    imagenes: [],
                },
            ],
        }
        
 let resultado = data.estudio.reduce((a,e) =>{
   if(e.active)
     a.push(data.estudioConfig.find(ec => ec.e_id ==e.e_id))
   return a
 },[])
 
 console.log(resultado)
```